# How to get HTML table values from external website?

Tags: javascript, html, download, cross-domain

I want to have access to some HTML table data for saving and using them offline. At the moment I use JavaScript and it works, when I download the webpage and put the JavaScript in that file. But I would like to get the elements either directly from the webpage without downloading it before or that the JavaScript download it automatically and get the elements from the downloaded file.

Is that possible? I couldn't find an answer because everyone was asking for their own webpage, but I do not own the websites I want to get the table data from.

My code so far:

```
function showTableData() {
    var tableData = document.getElementsByClassName('homeonly');

    for (i = 1; i < tableData[0].rows.length; i++) {

        var objCells = tableData[0].rows.item(i).cells;

        for (var j = 0; j < objCells.length; j++) {
            if (objCells.item(j).innerHTML == "NAME") {
                info.innerHTML = info.innerHTML + ' ' + objCells.item(3).innerHTML;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`info` is the id of the paragraph element in HTML to show it.

Comment: Please show code you have tried.

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish is called scraping, and you can write javascript to do it, but a tool (like one of these https://www.scraperapi.com/blog/the-10-best-web-scraping-tools) might make it easier.

Comment: added the code I have so far

Answer (score 0):

First you have to be sure is it allowed by remote side (site which you want to download) and legally.

Just send GET HTTP request with URL and you will have html in response. You can parse html and find table and other elements.

If cross domain is not allowed by remote server you have to create some Backend with HTTP client which will provide html.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is to download the webpage's static version, and inject your javascript code onto it.

Or - your second option - which I find much easier, use Chrome's JavaScript console to execute your desired commands.

If you find this method limiting, you can find a web scraping node.js library and write your scraper in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web scraping. There are various web scraping tools in many languages. I am also python developer i have creaated many scripts with python selenium and scrapy. So i think this is best solution for your requirments.

Answer (score 0):

What you're proposing to do is most likely a form of an [xss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack, which most websites prepare for. The best thing you can do without downloading the actual webpage is by opening the Inspect Element tab on `chrome` go to the `console`. Then paste and run your function there since you'll have access to the DOM there.

[image]